# VBA : Open XML file with XSL in Excel

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xslt

I would like to open a XML file with VBA language on Excel, but when I do it, it like the XSL is ignored. 
Here is my code :

```
Sub OpenFile()
'
' OpenFile Macro
'
Name_file = Application.GetOpenFilename("XML files (*.xml), *.xml")
If Name_file <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Name_file
End If
'
End Sub
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Have you tried: `Workbooks.OpenXML Filename:=Name_file, StyleSheets:=Array(1)`

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !

Comment: @Rory : post as an answer and I'll up-vote it. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `OpenXML` method instead:

```
Workbooks.OpenXML Filename:=Name_file, StyleSheets:=Array(1)
```